# Prince Rupert's Tears - with Alumina?

Tags: ceramics

When molten glass is dropped into water you can get tear shaped objects which are both incredibly strong and which have massive internal stresses. Which means any scratch can cause them to explode.

Is this only a feature of glass, or would it apply also to molten Alumina (Aluminium Oxide)?

Comment: AFAIK, molten alumina does not tend to form amorphous phases upon freezing. Also, to melt it you have to go quite a bit higher than for melting glass. In short, alumina hardly has anything in common with glass.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So going to some 2000degC to <100degC in a couple of seconds still produces a crystalline solid?

Comment: Quite probably yes (though I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @IvanNeretin I assume polychrystalline?

Comment: Yes, sure. $\;$

Comment: YOu would have to cool in a couple of microsceconds to get amorphous phases in alumina